# Getting ModuleNotFoundError error on importing XLUtils

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

when i import XLUtils i am getting this error. Thank you

`import XLUtils`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XLUtils'`

Comment: but when i go to my python cmd and install its showing requrement already satisfied, then

go to pycharm i install xlutils package than also error comes. thank you

Comment: @DebanjanB can you please check thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package name is all lower case `import xlutils`. But before importing it make sure that it is added in your project interpreter in PyCharm settings. `File -> Settings -> Project: (your project name) -> Project Interpreter`, on the right top corner there is `+` sign, click on it and search for package name `xlutils` (all lower case), install the package and it should work.

Comment: ok sir all relevant settings i have done but thing is that when i am going to with lower case(xlutils) then it is showing now this error--->>> rows=xlutils.getRowCount(path,"sheet1")
AttributeError: module 'xlutils' has no attribute 'getRowCount'

Comment: I think for row counting there is function called `number_of_good_rows(path)`. Please check the [latest xlutils doc](https://readthedocs.org/projects/xlutils/downloads/pdf/latest/) for more information.

Comment: @Adarsh you are welcome. If this answered your question and helped you, can you accept my answer?